# Test cannot compile when importing specific library module

Tags: angular, jestjs

I want to write a test for an Angular component. We use Jest for this.

The component to be tested uses UI components from a library in the template. Like this:

```html
<!-- my.component.html -->
<mylib-tab-group>
    <mylib-tab>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </mylib-tab>
</mylib-tab-group>
```

In order to limit the problem, I currently have nothing else in my test except the initialization of a TestBed, which in turn does nothing other than just import the dependency to the corresponding lib module.

```js
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { MyLibTabsModule } from "MyLib"


describe('LoginProcedure-Feature', () => {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MyLibTabsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [],
    }).compileComponents()
  })


  it('placeholder', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

The only bad thing is that when you run the tests, this problem is printed on the command line:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MyLibTabGroupComponent' before initialization

      1 | import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"
    > 2 | import { MyLibTabsModule } from "MyLib"
        | ^
      3 |
```

When I look at the stack trace, the problem seems to be with the piece `deps: [{ token: MyLibTabGroupComponent }` in the compiled MyLibTabsModule module.

```js
MyLibTabComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.2.0", ngImport: i0, type: typescript
MyLibTabComponent, deps: [{ token: MyLibTabGroupComponent }, { token: i0.ChangeDetectorRef }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });
```

But unfortunately I can't do anything about it.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jest cannot find the component `MyLibTabGroupComponent` with the written references within the path "MyLib". By that I mean that the `import` statements from the files withing "MyLib" might be referencing relative files or paths jest cannot find. File paths configured on your `tsconfig.json` are the usual candidates to blame.

If that is the problem, to fix it you need to tell jest that, for example, `@your-custom-path-name` is to be replaced by `<rootDir>/app/your/app/folder`

This is done on the [transform](https://deltice.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string) part of your `jest.config` file. You might want to use [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) to simplify writing the necessary configurations.

Without more of your code it would be hard to provide more specific info.

Also, if you could provide a minimum reproducible problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it would help you a fair bit.